# Most Active Contributors Monthly Report - March 2019

Tags: discussion, most-active-contributors, announcement

## Welcome to the 18th edition of the monthly Ask Different Most Active Contributors Report.

Please don't hesitate to share your valuable feedback in the comments.

[image: TITLE: REPORT TITLE]

### Report for March 2019

This report includes the following sections:

1. Overall Most Active Contributors Award
2. Monthly Reputation Leader Board
3. Most Active Editors Award
4. Most Active Voters Award
5. Most Active Close Vote Reviewers
6. Most Active First Post Reviewers
7. Most Active Late Answer Reviewers
8. Most Active Low-Quality Post Reviewers
9. Most Active Reopen Post Reviewers
10. Most Suggested Edits Reviewed Award
11. Highest Voted Questions Award
12. Highest Voted Answers Award
13. Most Viewed Questions Award
14. Ranked 1st Summary List
15. Moderators Activity Summary

---

[image: TITLE: OVERALL MOST ACIVE CONTRIBUTORS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   nohillside, Allan         310
2   bmike                     270
3   dwightk                   150
4   grg, Nimesh Neema         140
5   Tetsujin, jksoegaard      100
```

**Note:** This is an overall ranking based on all activities. Maximum possible score = 1,150.

---

[image: TITLE: MONTHLY REPUTATION LEADER BOARD]

[image]A total of 1,795 users earned reputation during the month. You can view the full list [here](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/118/month/apple/2019-03-02).<sup>1</sup>

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE EDITORS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  EDITS
---------------------------------------
1   bmike                      87
2   nohillside                 58
3   IconDaemon                 56
4   Nimesh Neema               46
5   Allan                      29
```

A big thank you to all 17 users who edited questions or answers this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE VOTERS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  VOTES
---------------------------------------
1   PeterJ                  1,383
2   user97627                 592
3   Monomeeth                 345
4   bmike                     341
5   dwightk                   135
```

A big thank you to all 59 users who voted on questions or answers this month!<sup>2</sup>

---

[image: ![TITLE: MOST ACTIVE CLOSE VOTE REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   nohillside                 80
2   dwightk                    41
3   Allan                      36
4   bmike                      22
5   Glorfindel                 19
```

A big thank you to all 25 users who reviewed Close Votes this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE FIRST POST REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Nimesh Neema              172
2   bmike                     135
3   nohillside                134
4   Steve Chambers             92
5   fsb                        91
```

A big thank you to all 44 users who reviewed First Posts this month!

---

[image: ![TITLE: MOST ACTIVE LATE ANSWERS REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                      91
2   Glorfindel                 46
3   bmike                      41
4   Tetsujin                   40
5   Nimesh Neema               35
```

A big thank you to all 32 users who reviewed Late Answers this month!

---

[image: ![TITLE: MOST ACTIVE LOW-QUALITY POST REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                      47
2   nohillside                 33
3   Tetsujin                   31
4   Ɱark Ƭ                     15
5   Nimesh Neema               12
```

A big thank you to all 24 users who reviewed Low-Quality Posts this month!

---

[image: ![TITLE: MOST ACTIVE REOPEN POST REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                      17
2   nohillside                 10
3   Tetsujin, Ɱark Ƭ, dwightk   6
4   bmike                       5
5   grg, Mark                   3
```

A big thank you to all 13 users who reviewed Reopen Votes this month!

---

[image: ![TITLE: MOST ACTIVE SUGGESTED EDIT REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                      40
2   nohillside                 31
3   Glorfindel                 20
4   dwightk                    17
5   grg                        14
```

A big thank you to all 32 users who reviewed Suggested Edits this month!

---

[image: TITLE: HIGHEST VOTED QUESTION AWARD]

1. [How can I quit an app using Terminal?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/354954/how-can-i-quit-an-app-using-terminal)

   - Posted by: Brainmaniac
   - Votes: **20**
2. [Issues with new Macs: Hardware makes them difficult for me to use. What options might be available in the future? [closed]](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/352851/168832)

   - Posted by: javadba
   - Votes: **16**
3. [Is there a reason to prefer HFS+ over APFS for disk images in High Sierra and/or Mojave?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/354375/is-there-a-reason-to-prefer-hfs-over-apfs-for-disk-images-in-high-sierra-and-or)

   - Posted by: user11421
   - Votes: **9**
4. [Is xar preinstalled on macOS? [duplicate]](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/354143/is-xar-preinstalled-on-macos)

   - Posted by: johan
   - Votes: **9**
5. [How to disable or uninstall iTunes under High Sierra without disabling SIP](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/353204/how-to-disable-or-uninstall-itunes-under-high-sierra-without-disabling-sip)

   - Posted by: intuited
   - Votes: **8**

---

[image: TITLE: HIGHEST VOTED ANSWER AWARD]

1. [How can I quit an app using Terminal?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/354956/168832)

   - Posted by: user3439894
   - Votes: **24**
2. [How can I open an app using Terminal?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/355040/168832)

   - Posted by: grg
   - Votes: **16**
3. [How can I quit an app using Terminal?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/355032/168832)

   - Posted by: Matteo
   - Votes: **15**
4. [What does Apple's new App Store requirement mean](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/354422/168832)

   - Posted by: Mateusz Szlosek
   - Votes: **15**
5. [Is xar preinstalled on macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/354144/168832)

   - Posted by: nohillside
   - Votes: **15**

---

[image: TITLE: MOST VIEWED QUESTION AWARD]

1. [iTunes Store Sign in Failure: “%%appleId%%”](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/352946/itunes-store-sign-in-failure-appleid)

   - Posted by: dwightk
   - Views: **4,884**
2. [What does Apple's new App Store requirement mean](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/354421/what-does-apples-new-app-store-requirement-mean)

   - Posted by: Anuran Barman
   - Views: **2,994**
3. [How can I quit an app using Terminal?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/354954/how-can-i-quit-an-app-using-terminal)

   - Posted by: Brainmaniac
   - Views: **2,915**
4. [Cydia Impactor won't sideload](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/353817/cydia-impactor-wont-sideload)

   - Posted by: Sam
   - Views: **2,854**
5. [Issues with new Macs: Hardware makes them difficult for me to use. What options might be available in the future? [closed]](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/352851/168832)

   - Posted by: javadba
   - Views: **1,422**

---

[image: TITLE: RANKED 1st SUMMARY LIST]

**1.    Overall Most Active Contributors Award**

- [nohillside](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/9058/nohillside), [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**2.    Monthly Reputation Leader Board**

- [jksoegaard](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/77912/jksoegaard)

**3.    Most Active Editors Award**

- [bmike](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/5472/bmike)

**4.    Most Active Voters Award**

- [PeterJ](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/83841/peterj)

**5.    Most Active Close Vote Reviewers Award**

- [nohillside](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/9058/nohillside)

**6.    Most Active First Post Reviewers Award**

- [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**7.    Most Active Late Answer Reviewers Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**8.    Most Active Low-Quality Post Reviewers Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**9.    Most Active Reopen Post Reviewers Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**10.   Most Active Suggested Edit Reviewers Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**11.   Highest Voted Questions Award**

- [Brainmaniac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/307545/brainmaniac)

**12.   Highest Voted Answers Award**

- [user3439894](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/115523/user3439894)

**13.   Most Viewed Questions Award**

- [dwightk](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/70930/dwightk)

---

[image: TITLE: MODERATORS ACTIVITY SUMMARY]

In March our [Moderators](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) actioned **394 flags** with an average handling time of **41 minutes**. In summary, we also:

- deleted 180 comments
- deleted 228 posts
- closed 193 posts
- edited 234 posts
- created 84 posts
- created 589 comments

---

Please join me in thanking all contributors for volunteering their time to make this site so great. We appreciate the contributions made by all users, not just those listed in this report!

Keep up the great work! :)

---

<sup>**1.** Due to the possibility of profile changes over time, this link may not reflect the screenshot above.</sup>

<sup>**2.** Only users who have voted over 10 times in the period are counted in this metric.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

I’m continually humbled at how well collaboration works here. No system is perfect, but we’ve really assembled a crew that does an amazing job with the framework and community that has assembled here.

Thanks Monomeeth for the excellent accounting and distilling of this activity. It’s always an interesting read.

Answer (score 1):

Really grateful to interact with so many knowledgable folks here. What's really nice is that most of them are regular and pretty active.

Really value how all the regular folks contribute in such positive manner without any bias. I feel fortune to have the opportunity to interact with everyone.

There's something new to learn every single day, which keeps me bringing to the website. Every regular contributor has a distinct strong area and it's nice to have a community with such diverse skill set.

Kudos to @Monomeeth to taking time out from him busy schedule and compile the statistics. Have seen you inactive on the site for quite some time, missing your really comprehensive answers.

Comment: Thanks for your kind words Nimesh! :) Life has been busier than expected, but hoping things will quieten down soon. And yes, I'm also very thankful for all the folks who contribute regularly and usually in a positive way. We're very fortunate to have them! :)